How to get context for Room database and initialize it correctly in Android Compose?
I use Room database in Android app, to create it instance of context class is needed. I want to get access to database in ViewModel, but context can be obtained only in composables or activities, so i create ViewModel in MainActivity, and pass Application (Application inherits Context) class to it to initialize DB. Then I pass ViewModel to top-level composable.
It works fine, but Android Guidelines say that this should be avoided:

Strongly recommended:
ViewModels shouldn't hold a reference to any Lifecycle-related type.
Don't pass Activity, Fragment, Context or Resources as a dependency.
If something needs a Context in the ViewModel, you should strongly
evaluate if that is in the right layer.

and

Recommended:
Use the ViewModel class, not AndroidViewModel. The Application class shouldn't be used in the ViewModel. Instead, move the dependency to the UI or the data layer.

Where should I move database dependency then?

Hey you need to use dependency injection to get Dao of room database in viewmodel.
1.Hilt with Room in an Android application, including a ViewModel and DAO access
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "app_database"
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserDao(database: AppDatabase): UserDao {
        return database.userDao()
    }
}

Then in your viewmodel,
@HiltViewModel
class UserViewModel @Inject constructor(private val userDao: UserDao) : ViewModel() {

    val users: LiveData<List<User>> = liveData {
        emit(userDao.getAllUsers())
    }

    fun addUser(user: User) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userDao.insert(user)
        }
    }
}

Also add these entry points,
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()


2.Inject Application Context in ViewModel
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplicationContext(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Context {
        return context
    }

    // Other provides methods can go here
}

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) : ViewModel() {
    // You can use the context here
}

Also, add entry point on activity and application.

You can initialize the database in your Application code.
class App : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        applicationContext = this
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var applicationContext: App
            private set

        val db: AppDatabase by lazy {
            Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "app").build()
        }

    }
}

Now you can use App.db to get the database instance.

So, this method does same thing as data injection with hilt, but manually?

Yes. Hilt is too much just to get the DB which can be initialized as a companion variable in the Application.
https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/manual

You can create a later init variable before the call of the onCreate function, and then assign the value to the variable after calling overrive on the onCreate function. This will enable you to use the function globally in the app and then migrate the viewmodel outside of the main activity, in a seperate file.
